# What is the number of items I must purchase to maximise my points?

Tags: combinations, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I have a total of $1,000. Item A costs 110, item B costs 90, item C costs 70, item D costs 40 and item E costs 45. For every item D that I purchase, I must also buy two of item B. For every item A, I must buy one of item C. For every item E, I must also buy two of item D and one of item B. For every item purchased I earn 1000 points and for every rupee not spent I earn a penalty of 1500 points. My objective is to maximise the points I earn. What is the number of items that I must purchase to maximise my points?

**Spoiler:**
I have solved this on my own getting 2 solutions as follows:

3 sets are possible-

Set 1: Total cost (A, C)
= 110 + 70 = 180
Set2: Total cost (D, 2B)
= 40 + 180 = 220
Set 3: Total cost (E, 2D, B) = 45 + 80 + 90 = 215

To maximise the points till 980- we can buy 2*Set2 and 3*Set1 with a total of 12 items.

Or, we can simply buy 13Cs and 1B to reach 1000 with a total of 14 items, no penalty.

The given solution says- 3*Set1 + 2*Set3 to reach 970 with 14 items!

Please point out where I have made a mistake..(if I have)

Comment: Just to check if I understand this correctly, if you buy three set1s and two set3s you get 9+8 items so that is 17,000 points but if you buy 13 Cs and 1 B you only get 14,000 points, but the rupee-related loss is $30\times 1500$ for the solution in the book?

Comment: @SuzuHirose there would be 14 items if you bug 3Set1s and 2Set3s, please check again. Also there will be a penalty of 1500 x 30= 45000 since 30 rupees are not spent! 13Cs and 1B seems to be more appropriate, since total reaches 1000. But yeah the final answer “14” remains the same

Comment: Sorry I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

If I buy this item-vector $(1,2,7,1,4)$, then the cost is precisely $1000$, so there is no penalty, and I have purchased $15$ items, which is larger than what your solutions show.
Your mistake is probably in setting up the constraints for the problem. For example, the sentence "For every item D that I purchase, I must also buy two of item B" ought to be interpreted as $b\geq 2d$ and not $b=2d$, where $b$ is the number of B-items purchased and $d$ - the number of D-items purchased. Similarly, the other two constraints also ought to be interpreted as inequalities.